# 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.slf4j:slf4j-jcl:jar is missing

Tags: java, maven, github

I was trying to import most of maven based project from the Github repository and once I imported all the projects, this is what I am seeing on my console -

```
Project build error: 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.slf4j:slf4j-jcl:jar is missing.  pom.xml /testdemo   line 23 Maven pom Loading Problem
Project build error: 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar is missing.  pom.xml /testdemo   line 28 Maven pom Loading Problem
null (org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources:default-resources:process-resources)    pom.xml /testdemo   line 3  Maven Build Problem
null (org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources:default-testResources:process-test-resources)   pom.xml /testdemo   line 3  Maven Build Problem
```

There is some error complaining about `org.slf4j:slf4j-jcl:jar` missing.

I am not sure how to fix this issue? Any thoughts?

This is what in my pom.xml file -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-jcl</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Version of the library is missing, try this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-jcl</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>     
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 4):

You're missing the `<version>` tag from your `<dependency>` block.

For example:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-jcl</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 4):

As said here you are missing the required version number.

Maybe you copied your code from somewhere else (not a bad thing, I do it, just saying) and then edited it a bit?  You can also specify your version numbers at the top like so, to help with readability and/or maintainability:

```
<properties>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>
    <logback.version>1.0.9</logback.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```